# What does "style xyz.css" inside a javascript file mean

Tags: javascript, css

Recently i saw an open source javascript library have a line like :

```
"style style.css"

var x=0
var ver=1
```

What is the significance of the style directive like above inside a javascript file? Is it some kind of directive for an editor or something ?

Comment: As it is, this is a nonsensical question. More (much more) information is needed to comment, much less answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you don't know the answer it doesn't mean its nonsensical. See Michał Šrajer answer below. Plus if you think the question can be worded better then its better to edit the question and fix it rather than commenting.

Comment: Newbie, a comment is a comment; I didn't add this as an answer for a reason. Personally, I've never seen this in practice (10+ years), but my comment actually meant *tell me more about **where** you found the code you included*.

Comment: https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/blob/master/scrollability.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the javascript point of view the semantic of the first line is more or less [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).
It's just an expression to be trivially evaluated.

This trick is used for example for declaration of javascript [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode).

In your example, it seems to be used to put **some metadata** into the script.
It's very handy method for it's backward compatibility with older javascript engines (no extra syntax).

Comment: Thanks Michał, yeah i thought that it looks like some metadata for some editor or IDE.

Comment: @newbie: or some framework or library